# fetching data into dropdownlist and get the selected data in php

Tags: php, html, mysqli, drop-down-menu, data-retrieval

I am trying to fetch some data from databse and display it into dropdownlist and get the selected data using php.

> Code

```
<?php


    if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'Save'){
        savecategory();

    } 

    function savecategory() {
        $category=$_POST["category"];


        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "******";
        $dbname = "db";

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        if (!conn) {
            die("Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        echo"Connected Successfully";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO category_tbl(cat_name) VALUES ('$category')";
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
        {
            echo"Successfully Saved";

            }
            else{

                echo"save failed..!!";

                }       

    }


?>







<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>gallery category</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="post">

<!--division for category insertion-->

<div class="categoryEntry">
<table align="center">
<th colspan="2">Gallery Category</th>
<tr>
<td>Category</td>

<td> <input type="text" name="category"> </td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="submit" name="action" value="Save"> </td> <td> <input type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<!-- end of category insertion div-->



<!-- start retreive category data into table -->


<hr>
<br><br><br>
<div>
<table  align="center">
<th align="center" colspan="2"> Category List</th><br>
<tr><td>Select Your Category:</td>
<td><label>
<select name="Select" class="textfields" id="ddlcategory">
<option id="0">---Select your category---</option>
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "******";
        $dbname = "mydb";

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        if (!conn) {
            die("Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        echo"Connected Successfully";


$sql=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM category_tbl");
while($category=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
?>

<option id="<?php echo $category['cat_id']; ?>">
<?php echo $category['cat_name']; ?></option>
<?php 
} 
?>
</select>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I have write code for retrieving data but it can't able to show data in drop downlist.

help needed..!! thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code solves your problem:

```
<?php
{
    mysqli_select_db($conn, "db");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category_tbl";
    $query = mysqli_query($link1, $sql);
    echo"<select name='category_tbl'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<option value'" . $row['cat_id'] . "'>" . $row['cat_id'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
} 
?>
```

Comment: yeah it works fine but I want to get the selected item value and insert into gallery_tbl. gallery_tbl has 4 colmn i.e. gal_id,filename,uploaded_time and ca_id. cat_id is foreign key of gallery_tbl..  I am very new in php.

Comment: @Student Pass your Foreign Key ID in <option value="$row['YOUR_FOREIGN_KEY']">. Then Get This value by $_POST['YOUR_DROPDOWN_VALUE'] after submitting your form  Thanks

Comment: @WaqarKhan You should not edit code to that extent, you basically rewrote it. If you feel it should be so significantly different, then you should post your own answer, or use comments to discuss it with the answer's OP. From the code you rewrote, I do suggest you post your own answer here.

Comment: @clami219 IMO, the changes you approved by doing "Improve Edit" were too significant. They should have been rejected, not improved. The changed code should be added as a separate answer by the user suggesting the changes. Minor improvements are sometimes OK, but this changes a large percentage of the code.

Comment: @WaqarKhan Basically, your edit comment as explanation along with the code you changed would make a good answer. You should also credit the source of the code that you will have copied and changed.

Comment: @Makyen You are right. My apologies for that! I'm glad you noticed and reverted!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<select>
<?php
$query= "Select * from DB_Table_Name>";    //Your Sql Query in a variable
$execute = mysqli_query($db,$query);  // Execute your query..$db is your connection variable
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute,MYSQLI_BOTH))
{?>
<option><?php echo $row['something']; ?></option> //Use Your Table Name Instead of Something
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: You did not open <option> tag before.